# Multiple voltage regulators?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a 12V DC voltage and need to draw around 1A at 1.2V. A quick calculation gives me the following results:

\$P_{dissipated} = (12V-1.2V) \times 1A = 10.8W\$

That's huge!

Can I use multiple regulators like `12 to 9`, `9 to 7`, `7 to 5`, `5 to 3`, and `3 to 1.2`?

That would give me the following power dissipations in separate regulators: `3W`, `2W`, `2W`, `2W`, `1.8W`.

Is that ok? And the two voltage stages are higher than the drop out voltage of the regulators.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine

Comment: Can you use a switch-mode step down regulator (buck converter)?  They are usually 90% efficient, so the 1.2W output would cause a 0.12W loss.

Comment: A far more sane approach would be to use an inexpensive buck converter such as advertised here (for just $5.09!): http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-to-DC-Converter-Boost-Buck-Power-Supply-Voltage-Regulator-Module-/231110646714

Comment: @AlfredCentauri : Haha, really funny :D

Comment: @NickAlexeev : Thank you, wasn't aware of them ! I will take a look but shouldn't be a problem from what I've read for the moment.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri : Thank you, I will take a look at the datasheet :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing conceptually wrong with using a string of voltage regulators to drop voltages as long as you take the drop-out voltage between each stage into account. It's quite a common approach when multiple voltages are needed by different parts of a circuit.

If you only require the lowest voltage and want to stick with a linear regulator there normally isn't a lot of point. Your total power dissipated has just been shared across devices and a more direct approach would be to use something like a LM317K in a TO-3 package with a suitable heatsink.

But usually when dropping that amount of voltage at any significant current a switching step-down converter also known as a buck converter is more efficient and ends up being cheaper. Many pre-built adjustable output voltage modules are available on e-bay.

If you prefer something you can include in your design and solder to your PCB there are also many easy to use devices around such as the [TI Simple Switcher](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher_dc_dc_converters/index.html?DCMP=simple_switcher&HQS=switcher) range that include a web-based design tool. While I'm not aware of any with a 1.2V output there is also the [Murata 78xxSR Series](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/meters/dms-78xxsr.pdf) and similar devices that are switching regulators with a LM78xx pinout.

Comment: even if you can't easily get a switcher to output the 1.2v you can have it output something close and get a linear regulator to trim it down from there, that will reduce the power dissipation on the linear and result in less ripple.

Comment: A quick search at [LT](http://www.linear.com/products/switching_regulator) gave 63 hits for buck converters matching the spec.

Answer (score 3):

A buck converter is the 'best' solution. But if you want to use a linear regulator you can arrange to drop most of the voltage and power in a resistor.

Establish:

- Say, \$V_{in}min = 12V\$
- Regulator dropout voltage. Typically \$V_{dropout} = V_{out} + 2V\$,  but varies greatly with regulator.
  Use say \$V_{dropout} = 2V + 1.2V = 3.2V\$.
- Say, \$I_{max} = 1A \$.

The maximum allowed resistor size is given by this formula:

$$Rs=\frac{V}{I}=\frac{$V_{in}min-V_{dropout}}{1A}=\frac{12-3.2}{1} = 8.8 \Omega$$

Use a slightly smaller value to give slightly more "headroom" rather than too little. Say 8R2 or 6R8. Wattage of resistor needs to be chosen appropriately.

Comment: If energy is to be dissipated, a dedicated power resistor is a much better idea than giant heatsinks on active elements.

Comment: @oakad - Yes. As above. BUT the resistor needs to be designed for heat-sink-less dissipation. Some power resistors need to bolt to a suitable heatsink to dissipate more than a small % of their rated power. You can buy power resistors that will free-air dissipate hundreds of Watts without a heatsink, but cost is usually high. Nichrome wire can be used to make your own free-air dissipating power resistors.